# How to let each sub queue and sub topic to reply to main QueueMessageSender thru bridge?

Tags: tibco, tibco-ems, tibco-topic

I have a project as attached pic and 
it has 1 main entry as QueueReceiver with queue of queue.sample to receive message then send to TopicPublisher to send to bridge, through bridge, it sends to 3 different sub queues and 2 different sub topics;

they are:

```
 Sub queues:
  sample.queue.sub.1 
  sample.queue.sub.2 
  sample.queue.sub.3 

Sub Topics:
  sample.topic.1 
  sample.topic.2
```

I hope
Let each sub processes once receive message from bridge then to reply to the QueueReceiver so QueueMessageSender will receive each reply.
I tested many times but failed;
Please advice How to let each sub queue and sub topic to reply to main QueueMessageSender through bridge???

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If I read your question correctly you are trying to reply using the same bridge definition, however, on the EMS a bridge is one-way, it has a source and a target. You must create separate destinations and bridges for the response path back to the sender.